# Is there a shorthand to Object.keys.map

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary, key, lodash

I want to turn an object into an array of its keys, and then map this array to something else.

```
var a = { b:1, c:2};
Object.keys(a).map((key,i) => {
  /*return some transformation of key*/
})
```

Is there any function in lodash for this which does the same thing?

Object.keys => map it to some other transformed array

If I use

```
_.keys(object).map((key) => {
  /*return key transformation*/
})
```

Is this fast enough - or is there some other lodash function for this??

Answer (score 3):

Lodash's map function works for this. Lodash sometimes gets a bad rep for being a large library, but you can download only the map function with this https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.map.

Once you have it, it works like this:

```
import map from 'lodash.map';
const a = { b:1, c:2 };
map(a, (val, key) => {
  /*return some transformation of key and/or val*/
})
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: awesome thanks it works: i did 
import { map } from 'lodash'

Comment: Awesome! Yeah that works as well, I just often hear people complaining about full lodash installs due to the size so I thought I would throw that out there haha.

Answer (score 0):

This is realy easy to implement using pure javascript:

```js
const map = Object.prototype.map = function (func, object) {
    const iterate = object || this
    const keys = Object.keys(iterate)
    const obj = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        const key = keys[i]
        obj[key] = func(key, iterate[key])
    }
    return obj
}

const aObject = { a: 1 }

console.log(JSON.stringify(aObject.map((key, value) => value + 6)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(map((key, value) => value + 6, aObject)))
```

And you can use it both in functional style and object oriented :)

Answer (score 0):

One-line solution for a simple map from an associative array with `Object.entries`:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(a));

// const a = {b: 1, c: 2};
// 'map' will result into => Map(2) {"b" => 1, "c" => 2}
```

More info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#converting_an_object_to_a_map